# How to open new terminal tabs in the same terminal window using bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

my terminal - genome
I am trying to run some commands, each in a separate tab in the same window.
I tried using

```
gnome-terminal --tab -t "XXX"  -x bash -c "redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf; redis-sentinel /etc/redis/sentinel.conf; sudo redis-server; exec bash"
gnome-terminal --tab -t "XXX"  -x bash -c "mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf; exec bash"
gnome-terminal --tab -t "XXX"  -x bash -c "node server.js; exec bash"
```

But the problem is it's opening new windows like this:

[image: 1]

but I want it to look like this:

[image: 2]

Comment: Try to make a minimal reproducible example. Do not use commands like `cmd1`, etc. which we can't reproduce. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Give more information about how you start your script or command.

Comment: The option `--tab` doesn't exist in the manual you can invoke with `man gnome-terminal`. However, its use doesn't trigger any error. It is probably deprecated.

Comment: @PierreFrançois thanks for the suggestion, I edited the question, hope i created a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you, but the commands you use, like `cd /home/udaysrinivas/`, are not reproducible for other users. Please, try to simplify the example for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several `--tab` options:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e bash --tab -e bash --tab -e cmd1 --tab -e cmd2
```

Tester with gnome-terminal 3.30.2

Comment: This is the command i generated based on your answer ----
gnome-terminal --tab -e bash --tab -e bash --tab -e 'redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf; redis-sentinel /etc/redis/sentinel.conf; sudo redis-server;' --tab -e 'mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf;' ------ but it's not working